# Airflow DAG auto-refreshes every 30 seconds

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

I have a **DAG script in my airflow** and it auto-refreshes `30 seconds`. I want to either **disable it (or) if possible set to a higher time limit.**

Also, as suggested [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=63407290), I have set `min_file_process_interval` and `dag_dir_list_interval` to higher values and restarted the airflow server, but again the DAG is getting refreshed in next 30 seconds.

[image]

**Please suggest a workaround to disable this auto-refresh or delay it to more time interval. Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

Set [auto_refresh_interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#worker-refresh-interval).

`auto_refresh_interval`: How frequently, in seconds, the DAG data will auto-refresh in graph or grid view when auto-refresh is turned on.

`worker_refresh_interval` is for number of seconds to wait before refreshing a batch of workers.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** :-

`worker_refresh_interval=some_number`

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html#worker-refresh-interval

Set this variable to higher limit in **airflow.cfg** file and the DAG wont refresh until that time limit.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want the function to run except when scheduled, create it as task level code and not as top level code.  Every time Airflow parses the DAGs, it executes top level code.  Having features you only want to run when triggered wrapped in a task is much preferred then making global level changes to the airflow.cfg file.